How to cause RabbitMQ connection to close internally?
We have RecoveryConnection class, that holds RabbitMQ connection and recovers it on close.
To test internal close case, we used an old RabbitMQ bug: attempting to create exchange with non-existing type caused connection close with COMMAND_INVALID (503).
But in later RabbitMQ versions it was fixed (between 3.12.13 and 3.13.7) and now only channel is closed with PRECONDITION_FAILED (406).
Is there another simple way to cause connection to close internally (not with rabbitmqctl close_all_connections)?
